# a = !5 < a; what is exactly done in this line of code?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    float a =5;
    a = !5 < a;
    cout<<a;
    return 0;
}
```

this gives output " 1 ", help me out to understand this.

Comment: in short: `!5` evaluates to `0`, then `0 < a` evaluates `true` i.e, `1`, so `a = 1`. Just a suggestion, never try and write such code.

Comment: Why did you add the C tag here? You really should only use one. This looks like C++ code.

Comment: [C++ operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: @cherubim got it,thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`!something_here` will evaluate to `0` except the case when `something_here` is `0`.

Since `0 < a`, (`0 < 5`), `a` gets a value of `true`, which is `1`, when parsed as float.

Answer (score 0):

```
!5 < a;
```

This is a boolean expression, resulting in `true` or `false`, when casting `true` to an integer or float in this case, it results in `1`, casting `false` gives you `0`.

To make the code a bit more understandable this is roughly equivalent:

```
float a =5;
bool check = !5 < a;
if(check)
  a = 1;
else
  a = 0;
cout<<a;
```

The expression evaluates to `true` because `!5 == 0` and `0 < a` is `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Expression `a = !5 < a;` is equivalent to `a = (a > 0)`, and since `a` is initialized with `5`, `(a > 0)` gives `true`, which is converted to float value `1` then.

So why is `a = !5 < a;` equivalent to `a = (a > 0)`? Expression `!5` is equivalent to `(5 == 0)`, which is obviously `false`. `false`, when used in a comparison with a float value is converted to `0`, and `0 < a` is - at least for built-in data type float - equivalent to `(a > 0)`.